# SQL query resultset, I need to group by the resultset wiht the column "date/Fecha"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```sql
--START DATE
DECLARE @Inicio date
SET @Inicio = '01/01/2021'

--END DATE
DECLARE @Fin date
SET @Fin = '31/01/2021'


--LOOP
WHILE (@Inicio <= @Fin)

BEGIN
    

    --WHATEVER SELECT
    SELECT @Inicio AS Fecha, 0 AS Agente, 1 AS FE

    UNION ALL 

    --WHATEVER SELECT
    SELECT @Inicio AS Fecha, 1 AS Agente, 0 AS FE 


    --ADD 1 TO DATE
    SET @Inicio = DATEADD(day, 1, @Inicio)

END
```

And it gives this resultset:

[image: resulset]

BUT, i want to group all the resultset with the column **Fecha**

[image: column to group by]

can you give trace

**Adding the group by Fecha (what i need to aggregate the result to the date)** it look like this
[added the group by clause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1xvY.png)

But the resultset is repeating the header for each row:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5kmF.png)

Comment: I've removed the tag spam, please only tag what you are *really* using. I *assumed* (before looking at the images) that you were using MySQL, as you also tagged [[tag:phpmyadmin]], but those images look like SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)...

Comment: Why are you using a `WHILE` here? SQL is a set based language. Why do you want a separate result set *per* date?

Comment: yes... My bad. Sorry for that.

Comment: i want to just the result on that dates range, that's why i try to use the WHILE

Comment: But why not a `BETWEEN` or `>=` and `<`?

Comment: with the logic that i'm using i'm getting separated result. But what i want is just one result set group by the date

Comment: *"But what i want is just one result set"* yes, because you're using a `WHILE` and executing multiple statements; 1 for each date. This is why I asked why you aren't using `BETWEEN` or `>=` and `<`.

Comment: I think it would be the same with betwen, it would not solve the issue on having more than one row of the same date

Comment: ok, one second i'm gonna try using between

Comment: You're getting 2 rows because you have a `UNION ALL`. You are clearly stating you *want* 2 rows there... If you don't want 2 rows per date, why do you have a `UNION ALL`? If you want a single data set, why are you using a `WHILE`? We need some *meaningful* and **consumable** sample data and expected results here. And we need to know what RDBMS you are *really* using. Take the time to [edit] your question.

Comment: but where exactly should i include the between filter? can you give a trace, please

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: What do you mean can I give a "trace"? I don't have access to your instance to start up SQL Server Profiler and run a Trace against it.. Like I said: We need some *meaningful* and **consumable** sample data and expected results here. And we need to know what RDBMS you are *really* using. Take the time to [edit] your question.

Comment: The data in your images and the code in your question doesn't match as well. You define the column `FE` as either having the value `0` or `1`, but it doesn't have that value in the images. Add your comment `--WHATEVER SELECT` (which suggests the`SELECT` in the above isn't representative of your actual SQL) and I assume said value is coming from a table, hence my recommendation of a `BETWEEN`/`>=` and `<`.

Comment: im using sql server 2016

Comment: Great, [edit] your question to add that tag (along with [[tag:sql-server]]), @MeninoHori . And don't forget, when you do, to add that sample data and expected results.

Comment: ok... just one second

Comment: @Larnu i made a change on the query, adding the group by on the subquery

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY`? There's no aggregation. There seems to be a **significant** amount of information you are omitting here, and yet you expect us to be able to work out what you want without it.

Comment: SELECT @Inicio AS Fecha, 1 AS Agente, 0 AS FE

 ) t WHERE Agente <> FE
  GROUP BY Fecha

Comment: Again, why do you have a `GROUP BY`? There's no aggregation.

Comment: no, i'm not hiding

Comment: i gonna edit the question so you can see

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

your question is not much explanatory. If you want to get data on basis of days of months then you can use following query:

```
--START DATE
DECLARE @Inicio date
SET @Inicio = '2021-01-01'

--END DATE
DECLARE @Fin date
SET @Fin = '2021-01-31'

;WITH CTE AS  
(  
    SELECT cast(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Inicio), 0) as date) AS col_date  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1, col_date) as date)
    FROM CTE  
    WHERE col_date < @Fin     
)
SELECT col_date AS Fecha, 0 AS Agente, 1 AS FE from CTE
```

Comment: If question is not clear, you should vote to close instead answer it